# 'ValueError: Required parameter not set' Django app following AWS configuration and Heroku deployment

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have just deployed my Django app to Heroku, having configured the app to store media files in an AWS S3 bucket. Everything was working correctly in the development server, but when I try to access pages containing these images in the Heroku-hosted version, I receive a ValueError informing me that the required parameter 'name' hasn't been set.

A look through the traceback suggests that the supposedly nameless objects are the images. s3boto3 is also referenced. My configuration for AWS is detailed below:

```
# settings.py

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_S3_REGION_NAME')
S3_USE_SIGV4 = os.environ.get('S3_USE_SIGV4')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

# env.py

os.environ.setdefault("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "**********")
os.environ.setdefault("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", "**********")
os.environ.setdefault("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME", "**********")
os.environ.setdefault("AWS_S3_REGION_NAME", "eu-west-2")
os.environ.setdefault('S3_USE_SIGV4', 'True')
```

I've read suggestions that I may need to add an AWS_SESSION_TOKEN to the configuration, but I have no idea how to go about identifying mine. I've also read elsewhere that a session token isn't a necessary part of the configuration. I'm just looking for a steer so that I don't wind up wasting time attempting something which isn't going to fix the problem.

Here's the error:

```
ValueError at /accelerators/
Required parameter name not set
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://acceler8.herokuapp.com/accelerators/
Django Version: 2.2.2
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Required parameter name not set
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/resources/base.py in __init__, line 119
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.8
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 22 Aug 2019 08:34:43 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template /app/accounts/templates/accounts/base.html, error at line 39

Required parameter name not set
29              <ul class="navbar-nav">
30                <li class="nav-item">
31                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
32                </li>
33                {% if user.is_superuser %}
34                  <li class="nav-item">
35                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'accelerator_create' %}">Add Company</a>
36                  </li>
37                {% endif %}
38                  <li class="nav-item">
39                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'accelerators' %}">Companies</a>
40                  </li>
41                  <li class="nav-item">
42                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'reviews' %}">Latest Reviews</a>
43                  </li>
44                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
45                  <li class="nav-item">
46                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
47                  </li>
48                {% else %}
49                  <li class="nav-item">
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in 
_resolve_lookup
                current = current[bit] …
▶ Local vars
During handling of the above exception ('ImageFieldFile' object is not 
subscriptable), another exception occurred:
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
        response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
            response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
            response = response.render() …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/template/response.py in render
        self.content = self.rendered_content …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/template/response.py in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/template/backends/django.py in render
        return self.template.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in 
render
                return self._render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in 
_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in 
render
            bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in 
render_annotated
        return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/template/loader_tags.py in render
        return compiled_parent._render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in 
_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in 
render
            bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in 
render_annotated
        return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/template/loader_tags.py in render
            result = block.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in 
render
            bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in 
render_annotated
        return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render
            return nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in 
render
            bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in 
render_annotated
        return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render
                nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context)) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in 
render_annotated
        return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in 
render
        output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in 
resolve
            obj = self.var.resolve(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in 
resolve
        value = self._resolve_lookup(context) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in 
_resolve_lookup
                    current = getattr(current, bit) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py in url
    return self.storage.url(self.name) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py in url
    params['Bucket'] = self.bucket.name …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
expire  
3600
name    
'logos/Founderd_Factory_MkvklIQ.png'
parameters  
None
params  
{}
self    
<storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage object at 0x7fef0d5307f0>
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py in bucket
        self._bucket = self._get_or_create_bucket(self.bucket_name) …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
self    
<storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage object at 0x7fef0d5307f0>
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py in _get_or_create_bucket
    bucket = self.connection.Bucket(name) …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
name    
None
self    
<storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage object at 0x7fef0d5307f0>
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py in create_resource
                       client=self.meta.client)(*args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/resources/base.py in __init__
                'Required parameter {0} not set'.format(identifier)) …
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: can you share the code where you try to access S3?

Comment: Please show the *actual* error and full traceback.

Comment: See the Heroku docs on [how to set environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Comment: Error and traceback have been added

Comment: Please use the *Switch to copy-and-paste view* button before copying the traceback.

Comment: I can't find that option on the edit page

Comment: I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to take from the Heroku docs on environment variables. I understand how they work and I've added the configuration that I understand to be necessary based on what I've read. There also doesn't appear to be anything referring to AWS or s3boto3, which looks to be central to the problem.

Comment: The error tells you that the bucket name is `None`. So it wasn't set properly (`os.environ.get('AWS_BUCKET_NAME')` returned `None`).

Comment: Thanks. I had the AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME stored in my env.py file, but adding it directly to my settings.py file seems to have gotten rid of the error, although the images aren't displaying.